# Prove by induction $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\cdot2^{i-1}=(n-1)\cdot2^n+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

The question is:

Prove by induction that $1\cdot2^0+2\cdot2^1+3\cdot2^2+\cdots+i\cdot2^{i-1}+\cdots+n\cdot2^{n-1}=(n-1)\cdot2^n+1$.

I am stuck and don't know how to advance. How can I prove by induction?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You need to make sure you get an accurate statement of the problem - you have $i$ on the left-hand side, and $n$ on the right-hand side - that could easily cause you confusion. Induction has two parts - the base case, and what happens when you add an extra term. You should indicate where you are stuck with either element, and what you have tried.

Comment: Adam, do you understand how to prove by induction? (Ie: The concept itself of proving by induction?)

Ask yourself the following:
What would be P(0)?

How could I get P(k+1) starting from P(k)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem statement is missing a few key words.

What you're looking for is

> Prove for all integers $n \geq 1$ that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot 2^{i-1} = (n-1)2^n+1.$$

First you verify a base case by showing that this statement is true for $n=1$.

Then, you *assume* that it holds for some $n=k$, and then *show* that this implies that it holds for $n=k+1$.

You assume

$$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot 2^{i-1} = (k-1)2^k+1.$$

Now you want to show that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i\cdot 2^{i-1} = k2^{k+1}+1.$$

A good way to start from here is to break out the last term of the left-hand sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i\cdot 2^{i-1} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} i\cdot 2^{i-1}\right) + (k+1)2^k.$$

From here, you can use your assumption to substitute the sum in parentheses, and then rearrange the terms on the right-hand side to show what you want.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$((n+1-1)2^{n+1}+1)-((n-1)2^n+1)=(2n-n+1)2^n=(n+1)2^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

For the induction step use

$$(n-1)2^n+1 +(n+1)2^n = (n-1+n+1)2^n +1 = n2^{n+1}+1$$